# Convert strings into date in SQLite when formatting is not standard

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two database tables named Intra360 and DAILY where the field "Date" is containing date strings in either of the following formatting:

```
30/01/2012 (dd/mm/yyyy)
30/01/2012 00:00 (dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm)
```

I would like to execute the following queries to the database:

```
SELECT MAX(Date) from Intra360 WHERE Date <= "05/04/2013 00:00"
SELECT MAX(Date) from DAILY WHERE Date <= "05/04/2013"
```

I know that the date formatting is not the proper one YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM but I have been going through SQLite documentations and seen there are some functions (such as "DATE()") to convert strings into dates and more in general to make string manipulation. I have no knowledge of SQL so maybe I'm not even able to implement it properly. Moreover, I cannot touch the data stored in the database so I need to get them making the due manipulation directly through SQL statement. Could anyone help with this?

Comment: The built-in date functions support only strings with a proper format.

Comment: Is there no way to manipulate them from SQL? Sorry but I don't know the language, my question might be meaningless

Comment: It would be possible to extract the fields from the date strings, but that would extremely inefficient if you can't store the proper strings in the database.